# PTIJ: How could Proverbs say that there's no such thing as a woman of valor?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

As [Proverbs 31:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2831.htm#10) says:

> ?!אֵשֶׁת-חַיִל? מִי יִמְצָא
>
> A woman of valor? Can such a thing really be found?!

Clearly, the implication of the *pasuk* is that there is no such thing as a woman of valor. Yet, we know this to not be true. There are plenty of valorous women in *Tanakh*. Take [Devorah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deborah), for example. So what does the *pasuk* mean when it implies that there is no such thing?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the joke may not be completely clear here. I'm trying to play off the Aramaic usage of the word מי instead of the Hebrew usage. Improvements are welcome

Comment: I thought it was about a soldier trying to find a woman to marry -- אֵשֶׁת-חַיִל מִי , and then, the faith that we have that he will find one יִמְצָא

Comment: consider marking an answer correct.

Answer (score 1):

The verse should really be read מי ימצא, implying that מי will find her. As we well know מי is also short for the word מים  So in order to find a woman of valor you have to dunk her in water and see if she floats.

Comment: I think there are much funny directions to go with your creative 'Mi will find her', reading.

Comment: e.g. the first name of Mi Yodeya...

Comment: ראו מי ברא אלה...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple aspects involved here.

First of all, the term אשת חיל is wrongly translated as "woman of valour". It really means a female warrior. Indeed, there have been numerous female soldiers in the past (Devorah, as you mentioned, was one of them), and the Israeli army, for one, has numerous female soldiers - some are sergeants. So, there's no problem finding female warriors.

The problem is finding a female warrior that has all the characteristics that are described in the rest of that chapter. For example, there;s a verse that says:

> ידיה שלך בכישור וכפיה תמכו פלך
>
> (My loose translation:)
>
> She stretched her hands to the mill and her palms support the spindle

This implies skill at sewing or knitting or weaving; perhaps grinding. The point is, that a warrier doesn't have time to be at home doing this type of domestic work if she is on the battlefield. This is why King Solomon wrote an entire chapter and started it with the question, "Who can find such a woman?"

As to WHY King Solomon wrote about something that doesn't exist - well, perhaps, that's one of his many wisdoms that makes him wiser than the rest of us. This requires far more research than you can fathom.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the verse is referring to [Wonder Woman](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%9F) of DC comics in particular. Unlike real life valorous women, she is of course fictional.

Comment: In case anybody didn't get it, and didn't follow the link, Wonder Woman is called אשת חיל in Hebrew.

Comment: Commentless downvote?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is a clear case of the use of Hebrish i.e. the mixing of Hebrew and English in the same phrase or word.

Thus the word "מי" means "me".
So, it means **I** will find.

The reason why the word "ימצא" is used (which mean **HE** will find) rather than the correct אמצא (**I** will find) is simply because it is an English speaker who doesn't yet know all the nuances of the Hebrew language.